# Using custom cell with text field. Values in the text fields are dissappearing on scroll

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a table view to add the details of users. I am using custom cell.

```
import UIKit

class AddUserViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var typetextfield: UITextField!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

I have 7 section in table view with 1 cell in each section. I am writing below code.

how can i make use of the custom cell while creating the cells for table.

I tried but on scroll text field values are dissapearing.

Answer (score 0):

It is because tableview dequeue the cells for perfomance. It reuse cells and alloc when come to front (visible rows) and destroy when not in front (Invisible rows). So, If you have fixed number of textfield to take user input then it is better not to use tableview to do that.

You should use `scrollview` and put your `textfields` on it. Tableview is for showing larger amount of data or for that when data size is not fixed.

For collecting user details or register or login type of viewcontroller shouldn't require to use tableview.